# Why vuetify tabs slider disappear when copule with navigation-drawer?

Tags: vuejs2, tabs, vuetify.js

I'm coding a layout with tabs but don't know why slider-color of a tab was disappeared.

Here is demo: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vuetify-tab-0fyyy

Here is my video test on Ubuntu FireFox version 57.0.1 64bit: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wmxsajsunwd9tur/vuetify_tabs.mp4?dl=0

Step as follow:

1. At tab1, the "events" tab was actived with blue line
2. Click tab2
3. Click "MENU" to open side-bar, then click background to close
4. Click tab1, then you will see the blue line disappeared

Many thanks for any advice!

Comment: The blue line remains and acts normally for me. Can you check it after refreshing your browser?

Comment: I've updated the post for the video test, but I will try on some different browsers. Thanks @chisnall.io